# FTP Connect Error remote host did not respond

Tags: ftp

I keep on getting this message while trying to move files from one server to another.

ftp: connect: A remote host did not respond within the timeout period.

What could be the cause and how could I fix it?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check the server firewall
- Check open ports
- Check if the server or network is busy
- Check the timeout specified at the server